# Can I use the dispersion index for a variable that is NOT normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

If I have a variable graphed as a function of time, that is not normally distributed, does it make sense to use its (time-varying) dispersion index, $\mathrm{Var}(x)/E(x)$ to compare its volatility for different members of a panel?

For example, daily temperature for different cities, or weekly exports for different countries.
The reason I thought of using the index instead of straight variance or standard deviation is that the values are quite large for some members and low for others, and I would like to transform the series to make the trends comparable.
Thanks! I hope I'm being clear.

Comment: Note that this is very similar to the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Definition).

Comment: The coefficient of determination is usually used when data values are strictly positive.